# What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?

Tags: scala

What is the difference between a `var` and `val` definition in Scala and why does the language need both?  Why would you choose a `val` over a `var` and vice versa?

Comment: Loved this question as I wondered the same thing.

Answer (score 357, accepted):

As so many others have said, the object assigned to a `val` cannot be replaced, and the object assigned to a `var` can. However, said object can have its internal state modified. For example:

```
class A(n: Int) {
  var value = n
}

class B(n: Int) {
  val value = new A(n)
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = new B(5)
    x = new B(6) // Doesn't work, because I can't replace the object created on the line above with this new one.
    x.value = new A(6) // Doesn't work, because I can't replace the object assigned to B.value for a new one.
    x.value.value = 6 // Works, because A.value can receive a new object.
  }
}
```

So, even though we can't change the object assigned to `x`, we could change the state of that object. At the root of it, however, there was a `var`.

Now, immutability is a good thing for many reasons. First, if an object doesn't change internal state, you don't have to worry if some other part of your code is changing it. For example:

```
x = new B(0)
f(x)
if (x.value.value == 0)
  println("f didn't do anything to x")
else
  println("f did something to x")
```

This becomes particularly important with multithreaded systems. In a multithreaded system, the following can happen:

```
x = new B(1)
f(x)
if (x.value.value == 1) {
  print(x.value.value) // Can be different than 1!
}
```

If you use `val` exclusively, and only use immutable data structures (that is, avoid arrays, everything in `scala.collection.mutable`, etc.), you can rest assured this won't happen. That is, unless there's some code, perhaps even a framework, doing reflection tricks -- reflection can change "immutable" values, unfortunately.

That's one reason, but there is another reason for it. When you use `var`, you can be tempted into reusing the same `var` for multiple purposes. This has some problems:

- It will be more difficult for people reading the code to know what is the value of a variable in a certain part of the code.
- You may forget to re-initialize the variable in some code path, and end up passing wrong values downstream in the code.

Simply put, using `val` is safer and leads to more readable code.

We can, then, go the other direction. If `val` is that better, why have `var` at all? Well, some languages did take that route, but there are situations in which mutability improves performance, a lot.

For example, take an immutable `Queue`. When you either `enqueue` or `dequeue` things in it, you get a new `Queue` object. How then, would you go about processing all items in it?

I'll go through that with an example. Let's say you have a queue of digits, and you want to compose a number out of them. For example, if I have a queue with 2, 1, 3, in that order, I want to get back the number 213. Let's first solve it with a `mutable.Queue`:

```
def toNum(q: scala.collection.mutable.Queue[Int]) = {
  var num = 0
  while (!q.isEmpty) {
    num *= 10
    num += q.dequeue
  }
  num
}
```

This code is fast and easy to understand. Its main drawback is that the queue that is passed is modified by `toNum`, so you have to make a copy of it beforehand. That's the kind of object management that immutability makes you free from.

Now, let's covert it to an `immutable.Queue`:

```
def toNum(q: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int]) = {
  def recurse(qr: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int], num: Int): Int = {
    if (qr.isEmpty)
      num
    else {
      val (digit, newQ) = qr.dequeue
      recurse(newQ, num * 10 + digit)
    }
  }
  recurse(q, 0)
}
```

Because I can't reuse some variable to keep track of my `num`, like in the previous example, I need to resort to recursion. In this case, it is a tail-recursion, which has pretty good performance. But that is not always the case: sometimes there is just no good (readable, simple) tail recursion solution.

Note, however, that I can rewrite that code to use an `immutable.Queue` and a `var` at the same time! For example:

```
def toNum(q: scala.collection.immutable.Queue[Int]) = {
  var qr = q
  var num = 0
  while (!qr.isEmpty) {
    val (digit, newQ) = qr.dequeue
    num *= 10
    num += digit
    qr = newQ
  }
  num
}
```

This code is still efficient, does not require recursion, and you don't need to worry whether you have to make a copy of your queue or not before calling `toNum`. Naturally, I avoided reusing variables for other purposes, and no code outside this function sees them, so I don't need to worry about their values changing from one line to the next -- except when I explicitly do so.

Scala opted to let the programmer do that, if the programmer deemed it to be the best solution. Other languages have chosen to make such code difficult. The price Scala (and any language with widespread mutability) pays is that the compiler doesn't have as much leeway in optimizing the code as it could otherwise. Java's answer to that is optimizing the code based on the run-time profile. We could go on and on about pros and cons to each side.

Personally, I think Scala strikes the right balance, for now. It is not perfect, by far. I think both [Clojure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) and [Haskell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) have very interesting notions not adopted by Scala, but Scala has its own strengths as well. We'll see what comes up on the future.

Comment: A little late, but... Does `var qr = q` make a copy of `q`?

Comment: @davips It doesn't make a copy of the object referenced by `q`. It does make a copy -- on the stack, not the heap -- of the _reference_ to that object. As for performance, you'll have to be more clear about what "it" you are speaking of.

Comment: Ok, with your help and some info (`(x::xs).drop(1)` is exactly `xs`, not a "copy" of `xs`) from here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712877/difference-between-array-and-list-in-scala/2713483) I could understand. tnx!

Comment: "This code is still efficient" - is it? Since `qr` is an immutable queue, every time the expression `qr.dequeue` is called it makes a `new Queue` (see <https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Queue.scala>).

Comment: @Owen Yes, but notice that it is a shallow object. The code is still O(n) whether mutable, if you copy the queue, or immutable.

Answer (score 63):

`val` is final, that is, cannot be set. Think `final` in java.

Comment: But if I understand correctly (not a Scala expert), `val` *variables* are immutable, but the objects they reference don't have to be.  According to the link Stefan posted: "Here names reference cannot be changed to point to a different Array, but the array itself can be modified. In other words the contents/elements of the array can be modified."  So it is like how `final` works in Java.

Comment: Exactly why I posted it as is. I can call `+=` on a mutabled hashmap defined as a `val` just fine-I believe its exactly how `final` works in java

Comment: Ack, I thought the built-in scala types could do better than simply allowing re-assignment. I need to fact-check.

Comment: I was confusing scala's immutable Sequence types with the general notion. Functional programming has me all turned around.

Comment: I added and removed a dummy character in your answer so I could give you the upvote.

Comment: Why does Scala need both `val` and `var` definitions?  Why have I seen few occurrences of `final` data definitions in Java?  Do Java programmers simply prefer mutable over immutable variables?  Is this just a bad Java programming habit?

Answer (score 62):

In simple terms:

**var**  = **var**iable

**val** = **v**ariable + fin**al**

Comment: I thought it was more **var**iable and **val**ue

Answer (score 22):

`val` means immutable and `var` means mutable.

[Full discussion.](http://javaforyou.wordpress.com/2009/07/02/val-versus-var-in-scala/)

Comment: This is just not true. The linked article gives a mutable array and calls it immutable. No serious source.

Comment: Not true indeed. Try that val b  =  Array[Int](1,2,3)
    b(0) = 4
  println(b.mkString(" "))
  println(" ")

Answer (score 22):

The difference is that a `var` can be re-assigned to whereas a `val` cannot. The mutability, or otherwise of whatever is actually assigned, is a side issue:

```
import collection.immutable
import collection.mutable
var m = immutable.Set("London", "Paris")
m = immutable.Set("New York") //Reassignment - I have change the "value" at m.
```

Whereas:

```
val n = immutable.Set("London", "Paris")
n = immutable.Set("New York") //Will not compile as n is a val.
```

And hence:

```
val n = mutable.Set("London", "Paris")
n = mutable.Set("New York") //Will not compile, even though the type of n is mutable.
```

If you are building a data structure and all of its fields are `val`s, then that data structure is therefore immutable, as its state cannot change.

Comment: That is only true if the classes of those fields are immutable as well.

Comment: Yeah - I was going to put that in but I thought it might be a step too far! It's also an arguable point I would say; from one perspective (albeit not a functional one) its state does not change even if the state of its state does.

Comment: Why is it still so hard to create an immutable object in a JVM language?  Furthermore, why didn't Scala make objects immutable by default?

Answer (score 15):

Thinking in terms of C++,

```
val x: T
```

is analogous to constant pointer to non-constant data

```
T* const x;
```

while

```
var x: T
```

is analogous to non-constant pointer to non-constant data

```
T* x;
```

Favoring `val` over `var` increases immutability of the codebase which can facilitate its correctness, concurrency and understandability.

To understand the meaning of having a constant pointer to non-constant data consider the following Scala snippet:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map(1 -> "picard")
m // res0: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = HashMap(1 -> picard)
```

*Here the "pointer"* `val m` is constant so we cannot re-assign it to point to something else like so

```
m = n // error: reassignment to val
```

however we can indeed change the non-constant data itself that `m` points to like so

```
m.put(2, "worf")
m // res1: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = HashMap(1 -> picard, 2 -> worf)
```

Comment: I think Scala didn't take immutability to its final conclusion: constant pointer and constant data. Scala missed an opportunity to make objects immutable by default. Consequently, Scala doesn't have the same notion of value as does Haskell.

Comment: @DerekMahar you're right, but an object can present itself as perfectly immutable, while still using mutability in its implementation, *e.g.* for performance reasons. How would the compiler be able to separate between true mutability and internal-only mutability?

Answer (score 10):

"val means immutable and var means mutable."

To paraphrase, "val means value and var means variable".

A distinction that happens to be extremely important in computing (because those two concepts define the very essence of what programming is all about), and that OO has managed to blur almost completely, because in OO, the only axiom is that "everything is an object".  And that as a consequence, lots of programmers these days tend not to understand/appreciate/recognize, because they have been brainwashed into "thinking the OO way" exclusively.  Often leading to variable/mutable objects being used like *everywhere*, when value/immutable objects might/would often have been better.

Comment: This is the reason that I prefer Haskell over Java, for example.

Answer (score 7):

> val means immutable and var means mutable

you can think `val` as java programming language `final` key world  or c++ language `const` key world。

Answer (score 5):

`Val` means its **final**, cannot be **reassigned**

Whereas, `Var` can be **reassigned later**.

Comment: How is this answer different from the 12 answers already submitted?

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as it name.

> var means it can vary
>
> val means invariable

Answer (score 0):

Val - values are typed storage constants. Once created its value cant be re-assigned. a new value can be defined with keyword val.

eg. val x: Int = 5

Here type is optional as scala can infer it from the assigned value.

Var - variables are typed storage units which can be assigned values again as long as memory space is reserved.

eg. var x: Int = 5

Data stored in both the storage units are automatically de-allocated by JVM once these are no longer needed.

In scala values are preferred over variables due to stability these brings to the code particularly in concurrent and multithreaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Though many have already answered the difference between **Val** and **var**.
But one point to notice is that **val is not exactly like final** keyword.

We can change the value of val using recursion but we can never change value of final. Final is more constant than Val.

```
def factorial(num: Int): Int = {
 if(num == 0) 1
 else factorial(num - 1) * num
}
```

Method parameters are by default val and at every call value is being changed.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of javascript , it same as

val -> const
var -> var