# Scala vals can be modified

Tags: scala

I'm starting to play with Scala, and one of the first things I read is that vals are:

> variables that are assigned once and never change, and vars, variables that may change over their lifetime

But I'm curious why I can do this:

```
val foo = Array(1, 3 ,2)
scala.util.Sorting.quickSort(foo)
```

If I check the foo variable now is ordered, which means it has changed... also if I do print(foo), both have the same, so the variable is pointing to the same object (I could have thought that the variable just pointed to a new object)

Could anyone clarify?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1792207/298389) could help you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Array pointed to by the `foo` variable is changing, but the fact that `foo` points at that `Array` doesn't change. Try re-assigning `foo` and you will see what you are looking for.

Comment: Of course, I'm not very clear today, the pointer to the object cannot change but the object's value can, so I can make a foo(0) = 5. Thanks

Comment: @jasalguero FYI scala does provide immutable collections

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with val, but with Array. Although values are unchangeable, arrays are. If you are looking to stop this, you can use a class within the package immutable.