# What does it mean to set a mutable object to 'val'?

Tags: scala

I'm setting a java Pojo instance variable to 'val' & changing its state after it's initialized. Will this cause any issues since its really a 'var' ?

```
val st = new Pojo();
st.setInt(0);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's still a `val`. The *reference* can't be changed, but the object referred to can have its internal state mutated.

`val` means you can't do this reassignment:

```
val st = new Pojo()
st = new Pojo()      // invalid!
```

For this you need a `var`:

```
var st = new Pojo()
st = new Pojo()      // ok
```

Comment: so it seems there are different levels of immutability and val is similar to a 'final' method in java in that its level of immutability is just that its reference to an object cannot be changed? A val is not as immutable as described at http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29 unliess the developer codes the object that way ?

Comment: You need to make your referenced objects immutable (members declared via val). Of course those members need to be immutable too, and so on...

Answer (score 3):

it's not a `var`. Try doing `st=new Pojo()` again and you will see that you can't reassign a new value to st (the compiler will complain `error: reassignment to val`).

`val` does not grant a "deep" immutability, just that the value initially set (which is just a reference to an object that can be mutable) can't be changed to a new reference.