# Assignment of a var arraybuffer in a for loop : "reassignment to val"

Tags: scala, for-loop

As said in the title, I can't reassign a variable of type `Arraybuffer(Arraybuffer(Int,Int),Int)` in a for `loop`:

```
var ab1 = ArrayBuffer(le4: _*)
var ab2 = ab1 map (ligne => (ArrayBuffer(ligne._1: _*), ligne._2))
println("ab:" + ab2)

for {
    i <- 1 to ab2.length
    j <- 0 to i
} {
    ab2(i)._1(j)._2 = j match {
        case 0 =>  ab2(i - 1)._1(0)._2 + ab2(i)._1(j)._1
        case i =>  ab2(i - 1)._1(j - 1)._2 + ab2(i)._1(j)._1
        case _ =>  ab2(i - 1)._1(j)._2 + ab2(i - 1)._1(j - 1)._1 + ab2(i)._1(j)._1
    }
}
```

the key point is that `ab2` is declared as var but the change of an Int inside it is denied. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between a `var`, and a `mutable` object.

- `var` can have its value reassigned at will
- a `mutable` object can have its fields reassigned. Like an object with `var`s in it

You are trying to set the `_2` field of a tuple inside of `ab2`; tuples are immutable, and that's why it causes a compiler error.

Reconsider the data structure you're using for this operation. A `collection.mutable.Map` might be better, or anything else that has an `update` method which allows you to change values inside of it.