# Why can't Scala have declared but undefined variables while Java can?

Tags: java, scala, variables

This compiles:

```
public class SandboxJava { //Java
  public Integer cards;
}
```

But this does not:

```
class SandboxScala{
  var cards:Int //Throws saying the class must be abstract to have undefined variables
}
```

Now I know the fact that `var`s must be initialized but why does not Scala have this functionality of having undefined variables in the first place?

Comment: Most likely the designers believed having field which have not been initialised is a bad idea.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala

Comment: Having a field of type Int which is always null and can't be anything other than null would be quite strange. And having that is probably an indication that the code has a bug and that the developer forgot to initialize the val. So having the compiler complain about it is a good idea, IMO.

Comment: @JBNizet A Scala `Int` cannot be `null`, it's a value type (maps to the JVM's primitive type `int`) and not a reference type.

Comment: @Jesper Ah, sorry. Learnt something. Thanks.

Comment: If it would be a `var` instead of a `val` you could initialize it with the default value of its type using an underscore: `var cards: Int = _` (would set `cards` to `0`, which is the default value for `Int`).

Comment: The problem is neither Java or Scala, it is your example. `val` is somewhat equal to a `final` variable in Java. So your example should be `public final Integer cards;` and this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, a field that isn't explicitly initialized is still initialized.  References are automatically initialized to `null` and scalar values to `0`.  The fact that it doesn't need to be explicit is just a kind of shorthand or syntactic sugar.

Local variables are a bit different.  They're not automatically initialized, and they can be declared without initialization, but it's a compiler error to access them before initializing them.

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x;
        if(x == 0) {
            System.out.println("Hello.");
        }
    }
}
```

Results in

```
Foo.java:4: error: variable x might not have been initialized
        if(x == 0) {
           ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Because although they *look* similar, they mean different things (have different "semantics"). The Scala equivalent of your Java code:

```
public class SandboxJava { // Java
  public Integer cards;
}
```

is this Scala code:

```
class SandboxScala {
  var cards:Int = _
}
```

This has (practically) the same semantics as your Java example. In the code above `cards`:

- is public-accessible
- is *mutable* (because of `var`)
- is initialized to its "default value" (because of `= _`)

Note that it is precisely because `cards` is *mutable* (a `var`) that you can initialize `cards` to its "default value". That is: `val cards = _` does not work, for obvious reasons (you can not change a `val` afterwards, so you better initialize it with something meaningful).

As other answers have noted, your Scala version is wrong (for the reason I stated above: you *have* to initialize a `val` with *something*).

If one corrected your Scala version with this:

```
class SandboxScala {
  val cards:Int = SOME_INITIAL_VALUE
}
```

you could write something semantically equivalent in Java like this:

```
class SandboxJava {
  public final int cards = SOME_INITIAL_VALUE
}
```

Note in this case that the Java compiler would *also* complain if you failed to provide an initial value for `cards`.

Answer (score 1):

A `val` is immutable. It can never be set. What use is an uninitialized field that can never be set?

Comment: Exactly and OPs Java version is incorrect. It should be `public final Integer cards;` and this also doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Scala doesn't have `abstract` modifier when it comes to `def`/`val`/`var`. So when such a member doesn't have a definition it's considered abstract. That's why compiler complains when you try to declare abstract member in a concrete class.