# Scala infinite while loop even though condition changed to false

Tags: scala, while-loop, infinite-loop

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object nameList {
    val names = ArrayBuffer("placeholder")
}

class Robot {
  val r = scala.util.Random
  val letters = 'A' to 'Z'
  val name = {
    val initName = nameList.names(0)
    while(nameList.names.contains(initName)){
        val initName = letters(r.nextInt(26)).toString + letters(r.nextInt(26)).toString + r.nextInt(10).toString + r.nextInt(10).toString + r.nextInt(10).toString
        println("while", initName)
        println("while", nameList.names)
        println("checker", nameList.names.contains(initName))
    }
    println("outside", nameList.names)
    nameList.names += initName
    initName
  }
}
```

outputs

```
(while,LA079)
(while,ArrayBuffer(placeholder))
(checker,false)
(while,IO176)
(while,ArrayBuffer(placeholder))
(checker,false)
```

The while loop runs indefinitely, above is an output snippet. Why isn't the while loop exiting even though the condition is changed to false?

Big picture, I need to ensure that each `Robot` instance has a unique `name`--I'm open to alternatives to using a while loop.

Update: per Jason C, below code fixes reassignment problem:

```
var initName = nameList.names(0)
    while(nameList.names.contains(initName) == true){
        initName = letters(r.nextInt(26)).toString + letters(r.nextInt(26)).toString + r.nextInt(10).toString + r.nextInt(10).toString + r.nextInt(10).toString
```

Comment: You redefined initName -- one shadows the other.

Comment: `initName` is a `val`. It cannot, and does not, change.  The `initName` inside the `while` loop is a different variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because in your loop:

```
val initName = ...
while(nameList.names.contains(initName)){
    val initName = ...
    ...
}
```

You redeclare `val initName` in the loop. So now you effectively have two different values. The one in the `while` condition is the outer scoped one. The one declared in the loop has no effect on it.

I don't actually know Scala but from [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala) I'm guessing the solution is to change the outer one to `var` (so it's modifiable) and drop the `val` entirely from the inner one (so you're not redeclaring it).

Comment: Thank you, your solution fixed it.