# Swap out "var" from Scala code and use "val" instead of "var"

Tags: scala, immutability, var

I am very new to **Scala** and don't know how to swap out **vars** and use **vals** into the code. There are lots of vars in the code.

Below is just a piece of code:

```
var fa = new JsArray

val ra = Json.obj("key1" -> val1, "key2" -> val2, "key3" -> val3)

fa = fa.:+(ra)
```

*How to use val for fa ?*

***2nd Case:***

```
val a = 10
var dr: String = ""
if (a == 10) {
    dr = "true"
}
else {
    dr = "false"
}
println("dr: " + dr)
```

Here, if I put **val** for **"dr"** inside **if/else** then it cannot be access in **println()**. 
Is there anything help on it to avoid **var** ?

Comment: var = variable

val = variable + final

Comment: `val fa = (new JsArray) :+ ra`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matching is a good option to make `dr` a `val`, especially if you need to test `a` for multiple different values.

```
val a = 10

val dr = a match {
  case 10 => true
  case _ => false
}

print(dr)
```

`case 10 => true`  This essentially says "if ***a*** *matches* ***10***, then assign ***true*** to ***dr***"
`case _ = false`  This says "if none of the above case(s) matched ***a*** then assign false to ***dr***"

Note that `dr` will be a `Boolean` type in the above sample, which is much better than using a `String` to represent true/false. If you really need a string for some reason then you would do.

```
val dr = a match {
  case 10 => "true"
  case _ => "false"
}

print(dr)
```

Comment: Is there anything that replace "var" ? I think, "var" is not good to use in Scala.

Comment: There are no `var`s in above example now. In general, there are some use cases for mutable variables but you are right to stay away from them wherever you can. See that `dr` is a `val` not a `var` in the pattern match.

Comment: Yup. I got. I need to understand more in mutable variables? Is there anything help stuffs ?

Comment: Just google scala val vs var and you will find 1000's of articles on the subject. Start here maybe for a quick read - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I think using pattern matching in that case is an overkill and simple if expression would be more appriopriate.

Comment: Or just write: `val dr = a == 10`.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala, `if/else` is an expression that returns a value.

```
val dr = if (condition) value1 else value2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a val, you're not allowed to assign it a new value, so in your code example above, if you switch the third line with

```
val fa2 = fa.:+(ra)
```

then fa can be a val.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern matching is probably the best style for this case, but if you wanted the `if else` you could write is as this. Note in Scala when the `if` statement is evaluated it returns a result like any other code block.

```
val a = 10
val dr = if (a == 10) {
   "true"
}
else {
    "false"
}
println("dr: " + dr)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll just add, that perhaps instead of representing `dr` as a String it would be better to type it as a `Boolean`, and then you can simply evaluate it to the result of the condition:

```scala
val a = 10
val dr = a == 10
println("dr: " + dr)
```