# assign value in scala foreach loop

Tags: scala, bigdata

I am learning scala but got stuck in a simple problem. I wanted to assign a value to a variable using foreach loop.

for example:

```
List A
foreach x in A { variable b = x; => then some operation => print result}
```

can you please let me know how I can achieve this in scala?

Comment: what is the type of the List? is it a list of Int, String etc?

Comment: this can be any type, string, int, double. I need a generic solution which I can apply for all types of List

Comment: this is what you should do. val list: List[T]; list.foreach( x => var a = x; /* some operation */ )

Comment: unless you reassign something else, you might want  `a` to be `val` to make it immutable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is proper way of running a foreach operation on a List.

```
val list: List[T] = /* list definition */
list foreach { x => var a = x; /* some operation */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

1) You can use `.map` on `list` if you want to process it and want a list of something else back *(just like in maths f:A=>B)*

**input set**

```
scala> val initialOrders = List("order1", "order2", "order3")
initialOrders: List[String] = List(order1, order2, order3)
```

**function**

```
scala> def shipOrder(order: Any) = order + " is shipped"
shipOrder: (order: Any)String
```

**process input set and store output**

```
scala> val shippedOrders = initialOrders.map(order => { val myorder = "my" + order; println(s"shipping is ${myorder}");  shipOrder(myorder) })
shipping is myorder1
shipping is myorder2
shipping is myorder3
shippedOrders: List[String] = List(myorder1 is shipped, myorder2 is shipped, myorder3 is shipped)
```

2) Or you can simply iterate with `foreach` on list when you don't care about output from function.

```
scala> initialOrders.foreach(order => { val whateverVariable = order+ "-whatever";  shipOrder(order) })
```

**Note**

[What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1792207/432903)