# Why is the each iteration parameter val and not var in for loop in scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

I am Scala beginner and started going through "Programming in Scala". I came across the following code.

```
for (arg <- args)
println(arg)
```

In the book it say's **arg is of type val and not var**. Why is it so.

As per my understanding for each iteration the value of arg is changed, as it holds new value each time it is looped.

Following are my questions

1. Why is **arg** val and not var ?
2. As per Scala if it is **val** we cannot change the value (Since it is final in Scala)
3. Also will it create multiple objects for each iteration and how are
   the objects destroyed after the loop ?

Also i know the difference between var and val in scala. I have gone across this link. [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)

Answer (score 7):

In Scala, a for comprehension is syntax sugar over `foreach`, `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` combinators. When you write:

```
for (arg <- args)
```

The compiler re-writes to:

```
args.foreach { }
```

Since `foreach` introduces a fresh value for each element, you don't *actually* reassign `arg` to anything:

```
args.foreach { arg => // }
```

For example, if we take a look at the implementation of `List.foreach`:

```
@inline final override def foreach[U](f: A => U) {
  var these = this
  while (!these.isEmpty) {
    f(these.head)
    these = these.tail
  }
}
```

You see that `these` is a `var` which is being re-assigned as you iterate the list, so *internally* the Scala collection library keeps a mutable reference to the list, but from the outside each value of type `A` exposed to you as a caller via `f(these.head)` is immutable, so there isn't actually a need to reassign a reference to a value like in a C style for-loop.