# Both var and val are creating immutable Set, but var is allowing to add a new value whereas val is not

Tags: scala, collections, immutability, final

I am from Java background and trying to learn Scala.

There is an example as below in the book "Programming in Scala - Third Edition"

```
var jetSet = Set("Boeing", "Airbus")
jetSet += "Lear"
println(jetSet.contains("Cessna"))
```

The first line creates an immutable non-final Set:

```
jetSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Boeing, Airbus)
```

The second line runs with no errors.

Now, when I change the first line from **var** to **val**, the second line gives error:

```
<console>:13: error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
   jetSet += "Lear"
```

I am not able to understand the reason behind it. **val** corresponds to final and var is non-final. I am not assigning the variable to any new Set. In both the cases, the Set is immutable.

How is **var** or **val** impacting things here?

Also, when jetSet is immutable in both the cases, why is it allowing to add a new value to the set in the case of **var**. Does it not violate the immutability principle.

Correct my understanding, please.

Comment: Of course `var` violate immutability, better to pretend it doesn't exist

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)

Comment: It is not violating the immutability principle, as before adding 'Lear', I assigned the jetSet to a new temp var. After adding 'Lear', temp and jetSet were pointing to two different sets.

Comment: I think as the Set is immutable and when I try to add a new value, it tries to create a copy (new Set) and add the value and assign to val. As val is final, it does not allow. Hence += does not allow.

Comment: If I use a mutable Set, then val will also work. When I append a new value to mutable Set, the same Set will be changed (new Set will not be created). Hence, += will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Case: 1

```
scala> var jetSet = Set("Boeing", "Airbus")
jetSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Boeing, Airbus)

scala> jetSet
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Boeing, Airbus)

scala> jetSet += "Lear"

scala> jetSet
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Boeing, Airbus, Lear)
```

#### Case: 2

```
scala> val jetSet = Set("Boeing", "Airbus")
jetSet: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Boeing, Airbus)

scala> jetSet += "Lear"
<console>:13: error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.Set[String]
       jetSet += "Lear"
              ^
```

In case: 1 when var is used. `+=` is understood as follows

> `jetSet += "Lear"` is nothing but `jetSet = jetSet + "Lear"`

`+` will create a new Set with "Lear" added to it along with others already in jetSet Set.

Note that here only reference is mutable but set is immutable. `+` method creates a new set (new reference code will be assigned to mutable variable.)

case 2: When `val` is used. Compiler thinks `+=` is method and tries to find if such a method is declared in immutable Set class. So, it gives a compilation error in case of `val`.

Immutable Set has no `+=` method declared in it. While mutable Set as `+=` method declared.