# Scala: tuples as var

Tags: scala, tuples

Tuples are immutable in Scala, so why is it even allowed to declare a tuple as a var and not always val?

```
var pair = (99, "Luftballons") 
println(pair._1) // Ok
pair._1 = 89 // <console>:14: error: reassignment to val
```

Using ScalaIDE Eclipse, Windows 10

Thanks,

Comment: Having a mutable reference does not make the object mutable. Using var in this case just means you can do `pair = some_other_tuple`

Comment: thanks, and some_other_tuple has to be same type as pair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between mutable *data structures* and mutable *references* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala) for details.

In this particular case, you're using mutable reference to immutable data structure, which means you can only *replace it with completely different one*. This would work:

```
var pair = (99, "Luftballons") 
println(pair._1) // Ok
pair = (100, "Luftballons") // OK
```

As others already pointed out there's a convenience method `copy` defined for `Tuple`, which allows creating a *copy* of an object (potentially replacing some fields).

```
pair = pair.copy(5, "Kittens") // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your pair like this:

```
pair = (89, pair._2)
pair: (Int, String) = (89,Luftballons)
```

by a new assignment to the pair, not to the underlying tuple. Or you use pair.copy, like suggested by chengpohi.

```
scala> pair = pair.copy(_1=101)
pair: (Int, String) = (101,Luftballons)
```

Comment: how about `pair = pair.copy(_1=89)`, :)