# Mutable fields of immutable values in Scala

Tags: scala, immutability

Consider a simple class and a (immutable) value instance of it:

```
class MyClass (var m: Int) {}

val x : MyClass = new MyClass(3)
```

Since `m` is declared as a *variable* (`var`), `m` is *mutable*. However, since `x` is declared as a *value*, it is *immutable*. Then is `x.m` mutable or immutable?

Comment: `x` is immutable. That just means that `x` will always hold the same _instance_ of a `MyClass`. That instance might mutate but it will never be a different `MyClass` instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x.m` is mutable.

The following code is valid:

```
class MyClass (var m: Int) {}

val x : MyClass = new MyClass(3)

println(x.m)

x.m = 7
println(x.m)
```

**val** holds a variable that cannot be changed, but in this case it does not make it constant. Indeed, it can have mutable internal fields (as in this case through **var**). Conceptually, the **val**ue `x` owns an immutable *pointer* to the variable `x.m` (ie. you cannot change the container `x.m` refers to) but the integer itself (ie. the container contents) is mutable.

Related: [What is the difference between a var and val definition in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala)