# How can a Map or List be immutable when we can add or remove elements from them?

Tags: scala, immutable-collections

Below is a scala code to declare a immutable Map

```
var m:Map[Int,String] = Map(1->"hi",2->"hello")
println(m)
// Result: Map(1->"hi",2->"hello")
```

Here we are able to add or change the content of Map,                  then how can we say a map or list in scala are immutable

```
m=m+(3->"hey") 
println(m)
// Result: Map(1->"hi",2->"hello",3->"hey")**
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Map` is immutable, but you used a `mutable` variable `m` (because you declare it as `var`).

This line `m=m+(3->"hey")` actually creates a new map and assigned it to your variable `m`.

Try to declare `m` as `val` and see that you will get a compilation error.

But - if you will use mutable map:

```
val m = scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]
```

You will be able to update this map (while you can't do this with immutable map) -

```
m(3) = "hey"
```

or

```
m.put(3,"hey")
```

This is how you will update the content of the map, without recreating it or changing the variable `m` (like you did before with `m = m + ...`), because here `m` is declared as `val`, which makes it immutable, but the map is mutable.

You still can't do `m = m + ..` when it's declared as `val`.

Please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791408/what-is-the-difference-between-a-var-and-val-definition-in-scala) about the differences between `var` and `val`.

Comment: Anything declared as Val will be immutable. Even if u declare a Mutable map like below, it will be immutable   

val m=scala.collection.mutable.Map((1->"hi",2->"hello")

Comment: My question is not about Val and Var, its regarding Immutability of Scala Map/List. Scala doc says Map are Immutable.

Comment: Updating my answer - anyway it's better to avoid using `var` if you want to keep your variables immutables. (of course, unless you are using mutable collections)

Comment: Sorry, I still did not get answer to this question.

Comment: Updated my answer again, I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Your first comment is incorrect; `mutable.Map` is mutable even when assigned to a `val`.

Answer (score 4):

Even if you think that your question is not about `var` or `val`, it actually is: in your example it is very important whether `m` is defined as `var` or `val`. In your example, even though you see that the map has changed, it actually has not: your code creates *another* map and assigns it to the same variable. The map itself has not changed, because it is immutable. You can observe this in this code:

```scala
val m1 = Map(1 -> "hi", 2 -> "hello")

var m = m1
m = m + (3 -> "hey")

println(m)   // prints Map(1 -> ..., 2 -> ..., 3 -> ...)
println(m1)  // prints Map(1 -> ..., 2 -> ...)
```

If `Map` was mutable here, you would have seen that `m1` has also changed. Because you don't see this, it means that the map is not mutable, only the variable is.

Comment: Why would M1 change here when you have changed M( m=m+(3->"hey") ). Please verify your answer once.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Because right after `var m = m1` both `m` and `m1` are pointing at the same data.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar that is the point, actually - `m1` will *not* change. If `Map` was mutable, and the `m = m + ...` changed `m`, then because `m1` and `m` before the change point to the same object, you would have seen `m1` change as well. It does not happen, which implies that `Map` is immutable.